# "Nivea Sun protect & refresh" melted my tub

Tags: solvents, plastics

I stupidly applied spray sunscreen on my children inside our white, acrylic bathtub and the floor ended up with a white, very sticky residue that rubs off on things, but will not wash away with detergent. The sunscreen turns out to be based on denatured alcohol and contains Benzyl Alcohol, so I suspect it melted the top layer of the tub.

Is there anything to do to re solidify the surface or remove the sticky layer? I've seen refinishing kits at the hardware store, but I assume this requires a clean surface beforehand.

Other ingredients:

Denatured Alcohol,
C12-15 Alkyl Benzoate,
Homosalate,
Octocrylene,
Cyclomethicone,
Glycerin,
Butyl Methoxydibenzoylmethane,
Ethylhexyl Salicylate,
Acrylates/Octylacrylamide Copolymer
Butylphenyl Methylpropional,
Benzyl Alcohol

Product and ingredient list:
https://www.nivea-me.com/en-me/products/protect-and-refresh-invisible-cooling-sun-spray-spf30-40058082837740214.html

Comment: You might want to give this question at home improvement (diy) SE if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Common sense chemistry says water with household detergent should get the organics out of the acrylic, so it becomes rigid again. Give it a day or two. Afterwards try whatever your hardware store offers to polish acrylic surfaces.